# Convert centroid data to lat/long coordinates

Tags: latitude-longitude, wgs84, centroids

I have a geoJSON file from Alameda County, California, that says it is based on `"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }}`.  For a given parcel, I am getting `"CENTROID_X": 6049318.7740417197, "CENTROID_Y": 2116583.343045` which I am guessing is in feet but I would like to be able to convert to lat/long to be able to plot markers in Google Maps.

Comment: @Pointdump I am writing code in node; see answer below that references a helpful library called `proj4`

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for the references; I'm learning a lot!

Comment: @user2856 thanks for the suggestion; I guess the metadata `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84` references the shape coordinates but for some reason the centroids are different

Comment: Nope, who ever put the meta data in lied to you by the look of it. GeoJSON is normally in lon/lat (CRS84) but your numbers are too big

Answer (score 1):

Credit to user2856 as well (for suggesting State Plane California zone 3):

Using node for conversion:

```
const proj4 = require('proj4')

const statePlaneCaliforniaZone3 = '+proj=lcc +lat_1=38.43333333333333 +lat_2=37.06666666666667 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016001 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs'

console.log(proj4(statePlaneCaliforniaZone3).inverse([6067236.27979723, 2123145.85667419]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to user2856

**State Plane California zone 3**

Confirmed in FME Desktop (Form) and reprojected to Latitude/Longitude.

[image]